# If a given checkbox appears, always mark/check it (using Javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="form-component form-checkbox     ">
<input id="post-ad_feature_NOT_PROMOTED_selected" type="checkbox" name="features['NOT_PROMOTED'].selected" value="true"   data-siblings="#post-ad_feature_URGENT_selected, #post-ad_feature_FEATURED_selected, #post-ad_feature_SPOTLIGHT_selected, #post-ad_feature_WEBSITE_URL_selected, #post-ad_feature_NOT_PROMOTED_selected">
<label for="post-ad_feature_NOT_PROMOTED_selected"><strong>I do not want to promote my ad</strong><span class="error"></span></label>
```

Hello,

I'm using Javascript on Greasekit / Greasemonkey, and I want to always check the box. (I don't want to it affect other checkboxes on the same page) (The box is always unchecked by default, when the page is loaded, I want to override this)

Thanks

Comment: Is the box created dynamically, or is it present on the page at load-time?

Comment: I think it's present at load time. (The site is Gumtree.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the action that you're looking for, you can avoid using JavaScript in the first place and use the HTML `checked` attribute.

```
<div class="form-component form-checkbox">
<input id="post-ad_feature_NOT_PROMOTED_selected" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="features['NOT_PROMOTED'].selected" value="true"   data-siblings="#post-ad_feature_URGENT_selected, #post-ad_feature_FEATURED_selected, #post-ad_feature_SPOTLIGHT_selected, #post-ad_feature_WEBSITE_URL_selected, #post-ad_feature_NOT_PROMOTED_selected" />
<label for="post-ad_feature_NOT_PROMOTED_selected"><strong>I do not want to promote my ad</strong><span class="error"></span></label>
```

If you must use JavaScript, then you can run the following function after loading the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init()
{
    if(document.getElementById("post-ad_feature_NOT_PROMOTED_selected") != null)
    {
        document.getElementById("post-ad_feature_NOT_PROMOTED_selected").checked = true;
    }
}
</script>

...

<body onload="init();">
```

Comment: Ah, but I'm using Greasekit so I need to write it in Javascript, not HTML. (Unless I misunderstand how Greasekit works?). Thanks, though.

Comment: `document.getElementById("post-ad_feature_NOT_PROMOTED_selected").checked = "checked"`?

Comment: Hey, if you post that as an answer, I can accept it as correct and give you the points/kudos you deserve. :)

Comment: I did update my answer to include a JavaScript solution. But I agree; @apsillers got a JS solution first (and I'd give it a vote)